# How to migrate model changes in EF

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, tfs, migration

I have been using ef code first approach. I can apply model changes using migration which was came with 4.3 of Ef.  I want to migrate new model changes to test db when tfs build deployment is running. How do I?
Best regards.

Comment: Your best chance of getting a helpful response is to include some code or description of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Usually migrations work like that:

**First**. You enable migration via PM console:

> `PM> enable-migrations`

**Second**. Then you add some entities to your context, and add migration:

> `PM> add-migration Blabla_adding_Entity`

**Third**. Then you can apply it to the database:

> `PM> update-database`

If you want your migrations to be automatically enabled, just set this option in your Congiguration.cs:

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
```